# Move From 0 to "Max Amount" Over Time

Tags: unity, c#

I need to create Coroutine that moves from 0 to "maxAmount" over "duration".

Can someone please assist me with the proper way to create this loop?

Here is my attempt at it:

```
var t = 0
 
While(currentAmount < maxAmount)
{
          currentAmount = Mathf.Lerp(minAmount, maxAmount, t/5f);
          t += .05f * Time.deltaTime;
          yield return null;
}
```

This moves the amount from 0 to MaxAmount, however, it doesn't seem to take the correct amount of time. (in this case 5 seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out.

What I did was:

```
float t = 0;

while (currentAmount < maxAmount)
                {
                    currentAmount = Mathf.Lerp(minAmount, maxAmount, t);
                    t += Time.deltaTime/5f;
                    yield return null;
                }
```

Hopefully this helps someone in the future!

Comment: It would be more conventional to put the t increment before the Lerp - otherwise this loop does nothing the first frame.

Comment: Completely missed this! I'll go fix it now. 
Thanks a a ton, Douglas!